# Hiding away constraints in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If you use some function that has a bunch of constraints

```
f :: (C_0, ..., C_n) => ....
```

And `f` is used in the definition of `g`, then `g` requires these constraints as well. However, these constraints might refer to things `g` should not be aware of (since this might leak information about how `f` is implemented). What is a sensible way, assuming this is a sensible thing to do, of hiding away `C_0 ... C_n`?

I've tried something like (please don't pull off your hair):

```
class (C_0, ..., C_n) => CanApplyF 

...

g :: CanApplyF => ...
```

but, while this works, it leads to simplifiable class constraints warnings that urge me to use either mono local binds, or replace `CanApplyF` by `C_0, ..., C_n`.

Is there a way to achieve hide constraints in Haskell?

Comment: How would anyone use the function if it's unknown what it wants from its arguments?

Comment: @bereal the instances of `CanApplyF` would be listed in the Haddocks. Users just wouldn't know _why_ those are the allowed types and others not.

Comment: I'd expect one would still have to have a constraint saying what `f` expects, but in such a way that it doesn't leak any information about in implementation of `f`. So `CanApplyF` is an example, albeit maybe a terrible one, of how one could hide constraints. To give an additional example, suppose that `f` has an `Ord` constraint in a subfield of a type that `f` uses. Not only `f` would be leaking the `Ord` constraint, but also the subfields of the data it uses.

Comment: @DamianNadales How about passing the whole of `f` as an argument to `g`?

Comment: I don't quite see what kind of important implementation details may leak through the type classes, but If there's an exhaustive list of types that can be use with the function, hide the generic implementation and export only wrappers with the concrete types.

Comment: I am not sure what you’re trying to achieve here? Is this about leaky abstractions (i.e. are you concerned that with the way you wrote the function you might break callers if you change some implementation detail) or is this some misguided attempt at security (in which case you’re probably attacking whatever problem you have from the wrong angle).

Comment: @danidiaz I haven't though about that. That might work!

Comment: @Cubic @bereal in this particular case I'm not concerned with leaky abstractions or security. The particular problem at hand can be seen here https://github.com/input-output-hk/decentralized-software-updates/pull/141/files#diff-52016b65a851480c6c3698e8cdcbe03eR198  As you can see `apply` requires a bunch of constraints that require the client of this function to know about what's inside `Data.Payload p`. An alternative way to solve this might be to make `Data.Payload p` abstract and constrained by a typeclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I think what you've done *should* be the right way to do it. Actually `-Wsimplifiable-class-constraints` is a bit questionable, albeit definitely useful sometimes. Though, if knowledge of the constraints is actually a security risk, then I daresay this is probably hopeless. (Also, [don't do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), but that's another discussion.)

Possible workarounds:

- Make `CanApplyF` not a new class but merely a *constraint synonym*.

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
  type CanApplyF = (C_0, ..., C_n)
  ```

  This should work, but it's not a rigorous encapsulation by any means. It's trivial to find out what constraints `CanApplyF` really encompasses, and in fact (like with other type synonyms) they might pop up unexpectedly in error messages.
- Add a dummy method, just so `CanApplyF` is technically speaking not equivalent to the combination of its superclasses.

  ```
  class (C_0, ..., C_n) => CanApplyF where
    onlyFUsesThis :: ()

  f = onlyFUsesThis `seq` ...
  ```

  (This doesn't work just like that because the instance is ambigious. You'll need either `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes` with `-XTypeApplications` to make it work, or introduce some `Proxy`es.)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an analogy here with dependency injection in object-oriented programming. In OOP, it's not a good idea to know your dependecies' dependencies. It's better to know only your direct dependencies (or, more precisely, their interfaces).

Consider this code

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Prelude hiding (empty,insert,lookup,toList)
import Data.Foldable (foldl')
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

data Mappy m a = Mappy
  { empty :: forall b. m a b,
    insert :: forall b. a -> b -> m a b -> m a b,
    lookup :: forall b. a -> m a b -> Maybe b,
    toList :: forall b. m a b -> [(a, b)]
  }

histogram :: Mappy m a -> [a] -> [(a, Int)]
histogram (Mappy {empty, insert, lookup, toList}) = toList . foldl' step empty
  where
    step acc k = case lookup k acc of
      Nothing -> insert k 1 acc
      Just count -> insert k (succ count) acc
```

`histogram` knows nothing of any constraint required on the keys of the map that it uses internally.

Putting it to work:

```
mappy :: Ord a => Mappy M.Map a
mappy =
  Mappy
    { empty = M.empty,
      insert = M.insert,
      lookup = M.lookup,
      toList = M.toList
    }

main :: IO ()
main = print $ histogram mappy "aabbbccc" 
-- [('a',2),('b',3),('c',3)]
```

Instead of a record, perhaps we could work with a typeclass, one that had as methods all the "surface" operations which we required for the type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Kind

-- a dictionary
class Mappy a where
    type Container a :: Type -> Type
    empty :: forall b. Container a b
    insert :: a -> b -> Container a b -> Container a b
    lookup :: a -> Container a b -> Maybe b
    toList :: Container a b -> [(a, b)]

histogram :: forall a. Mappy a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
histogram xs = toList $ foldl' step (empty @a @Int) xs
  where
    step acc k = case lookup k acc of
      Nothing -> insert k 1 acc
      Just count -> insert k (succ count) acc
```

These solutions hide constraints like `Eq` and `Ord` from `histogram`, but make the client work more: now he has to assemble record dictionaries, or declare new typeclass instances.

Comment: "it's not a good idea to know your dependecies' dependencies. It's better to know only your direct dependencies (or, more precisely, their interfaces)."  